# Заполнение одномерных массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа

Нужно при помощи подпрограмм сформировать и вывести на экран массивы `A[15]` и `B[14]`. И потом, при помощи функций найти их минумумы и максимумы.

Проблема с заполнение массивов. Первые 14 значение обоих массивов постоянно идентичны и не пойму где ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void write(int M[], int x)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i < x; i ++) {
        M[i] = rand();
    }
}

void out(int M[], int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cout << i << ": " << M[i] << endl;
    }
}

void max(int M[], int x)
{
    int i,  max = M[0];
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (max < M[i])
            max = M[i];
    }
    cout << "Максимальное значение массива: " << max << endl;
}

void min(int M[], int x)
{
    int i,  min = M[0];
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (min > M[i])
                min = M[i];
    }
    cout << "Минимальное значение массива: " << min << endl;
}

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int A[15], B[14];
    cout << "           Массив A" << endl;
    write(A, 15);
    out(A, 15);
    max(A, 15);
    min(A, 15);
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "           Массив B" << endl;
    write(B, 14);
    out(B, 14);
    max(B, 14);
    min(B, 14);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `srand` нужно вызывать только один раз. Можно прямо в начале `main`.

Comment: А зачем минус за вопрос, к тому же новому участнику? Вроде как сформулирован не в худшем виде.

Comment: @ Ternvein, как минимум за не желание чучуть разобраться в том, что происходит и сложить 2 + 2. Значение массивов одинаково. Причина? Причина может быть только одна - rand() возвращает одно и тоже. Что могло повлиять на random? Только непонятный автору srand. Ну а дальше загуглить что это.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко, ну, с таким подходом можно вообще не задавать никаких вопросов никогда, по такому алгоритму можно найти любую ошибку (возможно поэтому я сам их и не задаю). Тем не менее это ошибка в логике программы, и если вы на данном этапе в этой логике не чувствуете себя комфортно - вопрос задан нормально. Да и правил не нарушает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Уж сколько раз твердили миру...

Вот это -

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

вызывается **ОДИН РАЗ** на всю программу.

Вы просто говорите в функции `write` - а начни-ка случайную последовательность **заново**, инициализируя генератор значением текущего времени. А поскольку оно определяется с точностью до секунды, а вероятность, что эта секунда перещелкнет между двумя вызовами `write` - мизерна, вот вы и получаете одну и ту же последовательность...

Comment: Вы его можете не вызывать вообще. Просто в таком случае последовательность случайных чисел будет одна и та же при каждом *запуске программы*. Если нужно, чтобы они были разные - вызовите `srand` один раз, скажем, в первой же строке `main`, и больше не трогайте...

Comment: спасибо, запомню

Comment: Господи, ну что за... Если вам сказать, что переходить дорогу надо на зеленый цвет - вы же не станете спрашивать - на каком расстоянии от края зебры... Ну если вам нужна предельная конкретность, и все написанное так и осталось непонятным - напишите вызовы `srand` перед `setlocale`. Боюсь уже писать, что можно и после него :)

Comment: я уже понял, просто ваши ответы поздно появились) еще раз спасибо